# Visual Studio Build Command Macros for determining the version of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, build, macros

Is there a Visual Studio build command macros for determining the version of Visual Studio?

I want a post-build event that runs something in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\TextTemplating\<My MSVS version>`, for example  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\TextTemplating\14.0`

We have different developers with different versions of Visual Studio installed, and this build event is currently hard-coded.

I looked [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) but didn't see anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the build command macro I was looking for. This did it for me:

`$(MSBuildToolsVersion)`

It resolves to the major-minor version number that I'm looking for (ie, 14.0).